# Small Lines On Webpage From Unknown Code

Tags: html, css, web, margin

On [this website](http://www.tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/web_design.html), there are lines on the side and top, almost as if they are margins, but I can't find the code that is the cause. What is causing those lines?

Comment: The body has a margin of 8px.

Comment: That website's giving me a headache...

Comment: A couple parts didn't upload and probably are glitching out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's part of the [user agent style sheet](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade). This stylesheet has a default margin value of 8px. You can see this in the inspector:

[image]

Comment: Just add `body { margin: 0px; }` to your stylesheet.

Answer (score 0):

The background color of the page is #000000 (black) as you can see in `assets/main.css`. However, there is a white #pageoverview over the black background.